# Append value to c.Json response

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to append a value to the returned response of my code, this is what I already have:

```golang
publisherShare := 25 // I also have this variable that want to append to the returned response.
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, nf) // nf is a row found and returned from database.
```

This returns such json:

```json
{
    "id": 105324,
    "title": "test title",
    "last_update": "2021-03-10T12:50:37+03:30",
    "created_at": "2021-03-10T12:50:36+03:30",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-05T05:46:39.352859604Z"
}
```

I need to have a json result like this:

```json
{
    "id": 105324,
    "title": "test title",
    "last_update": "2021-03-10T12:50:37+03:30",
    "created_at": "2021-03-10T12:50:36+03:30",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-05T05:46:39.352859604Z",
    "publisher_share": 25 // I want this to be added.
}
```

This is what I have tried so far, but it changes the schema and will not be backward compatible anymore:

```
c.Json(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"book": nf, "publisher_share": publisherShare})
```

but this is not the json result I want. I want `publisher_share` alongside other fields just like the json result I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can add publisher share to the same type as

```
type nfType struct {
    // All of the db row fields
    PublisherShare int `json:"publisher_share,omitempty" db:"-"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a struct that matches the structure of your json responce. Key is to add aditional fild to it like

```golang
type Responce struct {
   // other fields. They have to be written in same way to keep conventions
   // (Go-ish name and needed name as tag)
   PublisherShare int `json:"publisher_share"` 
}
```

Then when you handle responce you can just unmarshal and marshal json.

```
responce := Responce{PublisherShare: 25}
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &responce)
if err != nil {
  //handle error
}
newResponce, err := jsom.Marshal(responce)
if err != nil {
  //handle error
}
// newResponce is now in form you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new type. It embeds the type of the db row, and it has a field for the extra value. E.G: if the type of the db row is `DatabaseRow`:

```
type CompleteReturn struct {
    DatabaseRow
    PublisherShare int `json:"publisher_share"`
}
```

Later use it as:

```
complete := CompleteReturn{
    DatabaseRow:    nf, // Serialize in json as before
    PublisherShare: 25, // Serialize in json as publisher_share
}
c.Json(http.StatusOk, complete)
```